# I want to represent the location of pixel in image by a single number(either double or integer). Is there any possible way?

Tags: java, image, data-modeling, discrete-mathematics

I'm looking for Way to represent coordinates of two dimensional space in a single unique number. I hope you understand problem. I want to represent location of pixels in image. Any relevant suggestion will be appreciated..

Comment: Example Grid 4x4 => `{1=0,0} , {2=1,0} , {3=2,0} , {4=3,0} , {5=0,1} , {6=1,1}` and so on.

Comment: Add more information please. Do you know the size of the image? You could for example just do ((10.000*x)+y), but that only works if there is a maximum size. Or you could just enumerate all pixels (1, 2, 3...), regardless of row, which would also uniquely identify a pixel (see @Enzokie's answer above).

Comment: yes! Assume size as 500X500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, for 1920x1080 sized image, you can express your x and y coordinates in 4 digit format. If x is 150 and y is 950 then unique number will be 01500950.

Comment: Thank you. This contain exact answer as per my question. I'll try to implement this concept. Hope this will help.

Comment: How do i Mark as answer? I'm new.. I think there is issue of reputation.